# Quicklook plugin issue with M Lion

Tags: macos, cocoa, plugins, osx-mountain-lion, quicklook

I developed a quicklook plugin that worked well with all MAC OS X version before M Lion. I am trying to make it work on M Lion and Mavericks. I got struck on a simple issue but unable to get any workaround.

I debug the plugin and found an issue with getting bundle path using the following code:

```
[[NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier: @"com.mss.qlgenerator.pluginname"] bundlePath];
```

But i am getting nil with this statement because of which the plugin stops working.
Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with that call?  There isn't enough context here to figure out what is going wrong.

Comment: My "bundlePath" method returns a non-nil result in my Mavericks QL plugin. Could your bundle identifier be wrong?...

Comment: @Cédric: No, i have cross checked it, identifier is correct, moreover its working in all other version of MAC.

Comment: @Parcs, the return response of `nil` means the requested bundle cannot be found — check the path.

Comment: Is this code in the plug-in, or in an app in which you're bundling the plug-in?

Comment: @PeterHosey: This code is in the plugin.

Comment: Are you looking for the plug-in's own bundle, or another plug-in's bundle?

Comment: @PeterHosey: Yes, i want to get the plugin's bundle using their bundle identifier.

Comment: @Parcs: So, just to be clear: you're looking for another plug-in's bundle, then?

Comment: @PeterHosey:plug-in's own bundle.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why `bundleWithIdentifier:` would return `nil` for your own bundle identifier, assuming you got it exactly right (no typoes and same case).

Still, there's another way to get your own bundle from any Objective-C method: `[NSBundle bundleWithClass:[self class]]` (or just `bundleWithClass:self` from within a class method).

If you're calling this from a C function (which is likely, this being a Quick Look plug-in), you can substitute a class's name for `self`: `[NSBundle bundleWithClass:[MyClass class]]`. It just has to be a class that you defined in your bundle.

If your plug-in is small enough that you don't have any classes, you can declare and define an empty one just for this purpose privately in your plug-in source file. (Just don't reuse it between plug-ins—class name collisions are bad mojo.)